# TIFF imread() fail std::bad_alloc in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: opencv, tiff, ubuntu-14.04

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 and use cmake and gcc 4.8 with -std=c++11 flag to build OpenCV from source. Where I select "With TIFF" and "Build TIFF" in CMake-GUI. The simple code :

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
int main(void)
{  
  Mat rst = cv::imread("test.tiff",0);
  cv::namedWindow("testCV");
  imshow("testCV",rst);
  cv::waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

compiled by:

```
g++ -o testcv -I/usr/local/include testcv.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -std=c++11
```

When I ran it, it failed with info:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried compiling OpenCV 2.4.9 (Release) and 3.0.0-dev (in GitHub) source. But both of them has the same failure.I tried PNG and JPEG, they work well. What is the problem? Is this OS related problem? I used the same code in my Ubuntu 12.04, and it has no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

`std::bad_alloc` is not an OpenCV specific exception. It probably happens when the array to store the pixel values is allocated. Possible cause

- Your image is too big to fit in memory
- The TIFF reader gets confused when reading the image dimension

Since you compiled OpenCV by yourself, compile it in debug mode and step into the imread function with gdb.